# When clicking on the button response on other page?

Tags: javascript, php, angular, ionic-framework, native

I am new to ionic and when integrating the data with the api it's been complicated task, i want to tap on any button and select any emoji and want to represent that data on replace of the button which is been selected.

Api is been integrated

```
home.ts page
  async showReactions(ev:any){

    console.log("you have clicked the button");
      const reactions = await this.popoverCtrl.create({
      component:ReactionComponent,
      event:ev,
      cssClass: 'contact-popover',
      backdropDismiss: false,
      showBackdrop:true,
      componentProps: {viewtype : this.viewtype}
    });

    reactions.onDidDismiss().then((dataReturned)=>{
      if (dataReturned!==null){
        this.dataReturned=dataReturned.data;
        console.log(dataReturned);
      }
      console.log('button is dismissed');      
    });
   return await reactions.present( );
  }
```

```
home.html
          <ion-button (click)="showReactions($event)"  >    
                            <div>Like</div>
                            <div *ngIf="dataReturned"> 
                                <img  src="{{dataReturned.post_excerpt}}" />
                            </div>
          </ion-button>
```

```
reaction.ts
  like(r)
  {
    let data =r;
    console.log("you have reacted");
    this.popCtrl.dismiss(data)
  }
```

```
reaction.html
 <div (click)="like(r)" *ngFor="let r of reactions" >
<img src="{{r.post_excerpt}}">
```

Comment: can you expalin more of your problem

Comment: i have a button and want to give it  just like the same as the facebook such it gives emoji and all so there is reaction.html file been called.i am trying to popovercontroller controller on it,as i have triggered it but value's from the value is not responding  me back.

Comment: you mean your not getting data in onDidDismiss() method?

Comment: yes,after clicking on the button it should go onDidDismiss() method and perform the  given selected task on that click event only it's not happening..!

Comment: my meaning is i am not getting the value as per the selection of the data single time selected data i want to show it.

Comment: debug both events, if possible create a stackblitz and update me

Comment: it's not possible Chowdary, i want to get only selected value from the selected button.

Comment: then lets debug step by step...are u able to see  let data =r; in console of that ts file

Comment: yes i can able to see it.

Comment: then what about  reactions.onDidDismiss().then((dataReturned)=>?? are yoiu able to see data in datareurtned?

Comment: the values are been getting from the reaction to home page.

Comment: in that case what your expecting more?

Comment: i want to save any one index value from the api is been get that value.

Comment: i am getting all values added to every single segment how to do it with index...? in that single page.

Comment: then i need more info about, how your reactions data looks like

Comment: so if user selects like and if its index is 1, u want to save that index value of like in your database??

Comment: its in the the api format ,where the image={fdsf.fadsf} type used in..

Comment: sorry but won't share the detail's regarding the api formatted.

Comment: yes exactly mr chowdry you got the point now..!